# Weird crash when accessing NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, writetofile

I add objects to an NSMutableArray and print out its content.

When adding the first object it works and the array says count is 1.

When I add the second object, is shows the array has a count of 2, but when accessing the array directly after that the app crashes.

```
[sharedsArray addObject:noteToAdd];

NSLog(@"The count of the array is %d", [sharedArray count]);

// Write the array to file
NSLog(@"Filepath is %@", filePath);
NSLog(@"shared array is %@", sharedArray);

[sharedArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

The app crashes on either of these 2 statements

```
 NSLog(@"shared array is %@", sharedArray);

[sharedArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

because of accessing the sharedArray. I dont see why it doesnt crash when checking its count, but it crashes when checking its contents.

The contents is NSMutableDictionaries.

Cant post images.

```
0 objc_msgSend
1<????>
2 _CFAppendXML0
3 _CFAppendXML0
4 _CFPropertyListCreateXMLData
5 CFPropertyListCreateXMLData
6 -[NSArray(NSArray)writeToFile:Atomically:]
```

Comment: What exactly is the crash you are getting?  I'm not sure if you can NSLog an object like that, though

Comment: There is no crash log, I will post the stack trace. And I dont think it is with the print out, because if I remove it, the app crashes on the next line [sharedArray writeToFile....];

Comment: It seems it isnt the printout, but when writing a plist that already exists? posting stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a zombie. Your sharedsArray needs to be retained. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168327/what-is-nszombie)

You can call count on it because Objective-C just no-ops sending a message to a nil object, but a direct reference to the object causes a crash.

Comment: I was releasing something I shouldnt have been. The data that went into the array, was then released by the time the writeToFile needed it. Thanks though.