# iPhone App Crashes when adding data to UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview

I'm making an app, but when I try to add data to my table view, my app hangs here:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));
```

Here's my code:

```
UITableView *fileTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 46, 300, 369) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

[fileTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Canvas_Tile.png"]]];

[fileTable setDelegate:self];

MyFileTableController *cont = [[MyFileTableController alloc] init];

[fileTable setDataSource:cont];

[self.view addSubview:fileTable];
```

Yes, I am including the UITableViewDelegate and all of my classes including my app delegate are fine. When I remove the "[fileTable setDataSource:cont];", it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `MyFileTableController` conforms to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`. Also you are adding what I assume to be a `UIViewController` (`MyFileTableController` based on the name) to a view hierarchy (which requires `UIView`s). If you need to display `MyFileTableController` you need to do so modally or through some other means such as a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: MyFileTableController is the data source for my table view (a simple view subclass for UITableView) which I have already added to my view. Without the "[fileTable setDataSource:cont];" line, it doesn't crash. When I try to populate my table view with data, it crashes.

Comment: You need to add the crash details. If it is just an EXC_BAD_ACCESS then you need to enable zombies.

Comment: Sorry: The debugger outputs nothing, but the crash is EXC_BAD_ACCESS. What is "zombies," and how do I enable it?

Comment: NSZombie [what, when and why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168327/what-is-nszombie) ... [where and how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4)