# Memory graph / chart in XCode 5 during Debug

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management

What does "Memory" usage chart/graph exactly represents in XCode 5 Debug navigator window?

I have an iOS app project with ARC disabled and no-storyboard/xib (i.e. old style). All memory management done manually using retain/release/autorelease.

When I debug the project in XCode 5, the memory pie-chart / graph show gradually increasing memory usage as the app runs, exceeds 1 GB memory footprints within half hour.

Roughly, it keeps increasing by 0.1 to 0.3 MB per 2 to 3 second with very rare memory dips/decrease (of magnitude < 0.1 MB per 30 seconds).

[image]

Is this a concern (memory leak) with respect to memory management? I did memory analysis (using Allocations/Memory Leak through Instruments on XCode 4.6) but didn't find any leaks.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Found answer myself. Unfortunately I had NSZombieEnabled (Zombie object) for debug mode - see below - (menu **Product** > **Scheme** > **Edit Scheme**)

[image]

Typically NSZombieEnabled tool keeps even the released objects in memory to help developer find over released objects. Refer this link - [What is NSZombie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168327/what-is-nszombie)

After I *unchecked* "Enable Zombie Objects" option, the memory usage stabilized to about 10 mb (not always increasing) even after half hour app usage - see below -

[image]

**BOTTOM LINE** - Ensure to clear "*Enable Zombie Objects*" when you want to analyze memory usage.

Comment: FWIW, this was killing me. Obviously my release being profiled didn't match the same memory usage that Xcode displayed in my Debug build that had zombies enabled. Thanks for this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I was going nuts as I'd profile in Instruments and not see the same thing. I did check Enable Zombie Objects a while back.

Comment: Are you sure it works? When Zombie objects enabled - memory progress isn't displayed in debug navigator (at least XCODE 6)

Comment: very helpful!, Disabling Zombie objects in Xcode 8.2 shows the memory graph again.

Answer (score 3):

It simply measures the memory your app uses. So if it is increasing it must be a memory leak.

When using the leak analysis tools, I would use it as a guideline. It may help you find leaks but with all automated tools it may not find it all. As certain pieces of code (Especially the more dynamic pieces) may be hard to predict what they do memory wise for an automated tool.

Comment: When I analyzed in XCode 4.6 Instruments, it showed total memory usage going close to 1.5 GB but active memory column showing usage close to 2-3 MB only. Also, memory leak didn't flag any blots. What tool or practice would you recommend to catch this (leak!)?

Comment: Don't test on the iOS Simulator as it can be inaccurate is one suggestion. But here are some video links explaining situations where the memory leak instrument may not capture memory leaks. Part1: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tvEFwWItQU Part 2 : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBvBL_m2-5k

Comment: In Part 2 he recommends to use the analyse option as it can pick up memory leaks that cannot be picked up by the instruments tool.

Comment: These videos are useful (+1). Let me analyze & confirm your answer before I 'check' this answer. Stay tuned! :)

Comment: Found the real issue in my case (See my checked answer). However, I agree with your explanation in general (+1).

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing an issue where memory (heap) grows indefinitely on heavy processing but when running the exact same binary without Xcode; memory usage is fine. Remember to test outside of Xcode -- no idea what the cause is. NSZombies and all other debug options are *off*.