# How Find the Source of Memory Pressure in an iOS Application

Tags: ios, memory, instruments

I was debugging an app on a device. It worked perfectly for some time and then stopped with the error message "App terminated due to memory pressure". There is no error or crash logs.

Why did this happen? How can i resolve this? My app uses 10 to 30 mb ram while running. Is that a lot?

UPDATE:
after using instruments i got this.. can anybody explain memory allocation????

[image: ![]]

UPDATE:
 i tried instruments and found leaks. i got some thing like this

[image]

i cant understand what does it mean and how to solve this????

Comment: Try using Instrument's Memory tools to find out what is using the most memory.

Comment: Have you tried using Instruments? Specifically the Allocations Instrument?  Doing that should lead you to the source of your problem.

Comment: i didnt get what is this Instruments??

Comment: In the Xcode menu bar, under 'Product,' there is a profile option. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeProfile.html

Comment: okay... let me try...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think 10 to 30 mb of app's memory usage is not an issue especially for latest model iOS devices (like iPhone 4 and 5), unless you have lot of other memory intensive apps running in background. They have 512mb to 1 GB RAM.

*Diagnosis* of issue -

To begin with, use memory graph in XCode 5. You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394107/memory-graph-chart-in-xcode-5-during-debug) link useful.

Also, you may like to put breakpoints in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method provided by UIViewController.

And, to further dig down, switch to profile your app. (Xcode menu **Product** > **Profile** and choose **Allocations** in the dialog). Here, you will find a good [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks).

Comment: i am using core data db with my app.

Comment: Just added a tutorial link in my answer, which explains how to debug memory leaks.

Comment: while ram usage is up to 40 mb cpu usage is up to 70 to 90%