# Memory not being released right even dealloc method is called after dismissing view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiview, uiviewcontroller

What am I doing is I am creating lots of UIView in the background and keep them in a NSMutableArray to use later. But when I dismiss the view controller I check the memory in Xcode and it seems some of memory not being released. I checked; view controller is being deallocated.

Check please:
[image]

This happend after several showing and dismissing the view controller. Some of them is being released but not all.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you enabled Zombie in your project?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. @Student

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uncheck `Enable Zombie Objects` option under Edit Scheme. And try again.

A zombie is an object that has been deallocated, but references to it still exist and messages are still being sent to it

I think this link has more info for you 
[What is NSZombie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168327/what-is-nszombie)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use arc, so it might be useful to explicitly release this in dealloc.

```
-(void)dealloc {
    for(UIView *vw in self.arrayOfViews) {
        vw = nil;
    }
    self.arrayOfViews = nil;
}
```

Using dealloc is a bit like the old days (pre-arc), but it will help you manage memory better.
!important! --> NEVER call `[super dealloc];` when using arc!

Answer (score 0):

In dealloc method release all views that you have in the array.

called the below method in your controller dealloc method

```
- (void)releaseViewArray
{
// Releasing views in the array 
    for (UIView *view in _viewArray) {
        [view release];
    }
// Releasing the array that holding the views
  [_viewArray release];
}
```