# MPMoviePlayerController released, but memory usage still high

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using MPMoviePlayerController play online video (I'm using ARC), here's the code:

```
_moviePlayer = [[ZXMPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
_moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 320);
_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
NSString *sourcePathStr = @"";  //video url
_moviePlayer.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:sourcePathStr];
_moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[_moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[_moviePlayer play];
```

ZXMPMoviePlayerController is a subclass of MPMoviePlayerController in case of observing the deallocation of _moviePlayer.

Now I'm sure _moviePlayer is deallocated(because I printed log in dealloc method of ZXMPMoviePlayerController) after I leave this VC (VC is deallocated also.), but the memory usage of my app is still high, This is a test demo, the vc is clean except the movieplayer.
I think it must be something of _moviePlayer is still in memory, like cache of something else, I have no idea...

Any ideas? Help...

in .h

```
@interface ZXMPMoviePlayerController : MPMoviePlayerController

@end
```

in .m 
    #import "ZXMPMoviePlayerController.h"

```
@implementation ZXMPMoviePlayerController


- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you using "NSZombie" enabled in your project(under "EditSchemes")?

Comment: @Student yes, I am. and I found out that whether NSZombie is enabled doesn't affect the memory usage too much.

Comment: Ok then disable it, and check again. For more information check my answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521856/memory-not-being-released-right-even-dealloc-method-is-called-after-dismissing-v/25521933#25521933

Comment: @Student yeah, the memory is lower than before, but still cannot be released after the movieplayer deallocated. I'm not so familiar with Instruments, how could I know what exactly are keeping those memory? Living bytes, responsible caller, or category , none of them I could  find any clue... Thankyou!

Comment: Some links for you. hope it help http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode  

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/instrumentsuserguide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

Hi to be sure that you release memory wrap all code with `@autoreleasepool`. In the dealloc you should clean your memory. When you are using dealloc method you should check if all object are release to avoid memory leaks.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   [moviePlayer_ release];
    moviePlayer_ = nil;
}
```

**This how you should call video player.**

```
@autoreleasepool
{

    [_moviePlayer release];
    _moviePlayer = nil;

    _moviePlayer = [[ZXMPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    _moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 320);
    _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
    NSString *sourcePathStr = @"";  //video url
    _moviePlayer.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:sourcePathStr];
    _moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    [_moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [_moviePlayer play];


}
```

Comment: I tried this, and not work..
And by the way.. I'm using ARC :-)
Normally, if this memory could autorelease , when my app comes to background, the memory usage would drop, but when my app comes to background, the memory keeps high...

Comment: Than you should try to work with iOS instruments. To find memory leak.

Comment: Show you're dealoc method please as well,

Comment: I printed log in dealloc method of ZXMPMoviePlayerController, and the log show in the console after I pop this VC, so I think it's deallocated.

Comment: Show whole file where you are implementing this movie player.

Comment: Try now please and see

Comment: As I said before.. I'm using ARC... I cannot call release.

Comment: And I don't think I could call release before allocation of moviePlayer...
I changed the file to MRC, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck Enable Zombie Objects option under Edit Scheme. And try again.