# Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT in Xcode

Tags: xcode6

Getting error while running App in Xcode and shows error like this 
"terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

looking for your help

Comment: Please paste the actual full error message into your question instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: See [What is NSZombie?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4168327)